# Magento 2.2.5 Layered Navigation with configurable products is not working

Tags: magento2

It is not a duplicated question I have checked other questions and their answers. But did not work for me.

Magento = 2.2.5 EE

When I choose the associated products visibility 'Catalog and search' then filter attributes show in layered navigation but with the visibility 'Not visible Individually' then filter attributes does not show.

1) Category is anchor

2) Associated products and configurable products attribute set is same

3) There are more than one configurable products with different options.

Do you have any idea or hint why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I reviewed the code this is a possible solution :

Modified the file vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php

```
       if ($isAttributeFilterable && (!$this->isOptionReducesResults($count, $productSize) || $count === 0)) {
        return;
    }
```

to:

```
    if ($isAttributeFilterable && $count === 0) {
        return;
    }
```

I hope this help you.

**EDIT** this is fixed in the version 2.3 of magento https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/573f74764a23877866ae7627fc43884164668899

Comment: You just removed a condition. Why? Why does your code work? Where did you found this trick? Or how did you find out. Can you give us some details?

Comment: this problem is fixed by magento in this commit https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/573f74764a23877866ae7627fc43884164668899